# django: use QuerySet.values() to return Python types?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a custom `Field` which converts the value to/from a Python type:

```
class MyField(models.Field):
    # …
    def to_python(self, value):
        # …
        return MyType(value)
```

Is there any way to trick `QuerySet.values(…)` into running the field-specific conversions on the values it returns?

For example, I'd like something like this:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.all().values("my_field")
[{"my_field": MyType(…)}]
```

Instead of the current behaviour:

```
>>> MyModel.objects.all().values("my_field")
[{"my_field": "raw_database_value"}]
```

Obviously I can manually convert the result… But that's kind of lame =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. You can see the related ticket at https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9619

There you will see there is discussion whether `values()` should actually run any field-specific conversions.

As the ticket is marked "Design Decision Needed", you'd need to bring this up by posting to the [django-developers mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers), or raising it with someone on IRC (Freenode #django-dev)

In the meantime, you will have to manually convert the raw database value.